# OSGi: Unable to get module class path

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am facing a problem with one of my OSGi bundles. 
When I start it, I have the following error :

```
ERROR: Bundle nsis-common-referentiel [457] Unable to get module class
path. (java.lang.NullPointerException) java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.calculateContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.initializeContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:365)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.getContentPath(BundleRevisionImpl.java:351)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.getResourcesLocal(BundleRevisionImpl.java:515)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findResourcesByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1190)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getResourcesByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1100)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.getResources(BundleWiringImpl.java:2576)
        at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiClassLoader.findResources(OsgiClassLoader.java:168)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1142)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:186)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:348)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:339)
        at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:518)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:112)
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.createEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:432)
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.registerEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.access$000(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:74)
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:203)
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager$1.call(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It is not blocking for starting my bundle, it is "Active". But when I try to execute a SQL command through my Java code, it only works with native queries. When I try to execute HQL queries/named queries, I always have errors such as

```
ClassCastException: com.example.MyBean cannot be cast to com.example.MyBean
```

I guess it is linked to the first error. What do you think about that? Do you know how to prevent the first error?

Do not hesitate if you need more information.

Thanks a lot,
Hejk

Comment: The problem is that the instance of MyBean is not created by the same classloader that tries to cast MyBean. How do your bundels look like? Is Hibernate a separate bundle?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have a bundle bundleA which contains persistence configuration, beans (like MyBean), managers, etc. I also have bundleB which uses a service exposed by bundleA. So the error appears when I call bundleA service through bundleB. Alongside bundleA and bundleB, I have hibernate-osgi, hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-core and hibernate-commons-annotations bundles in version 4.3.6.Final. Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the version of Apache Felix you are using.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I am using ServiceMix 7.0.1 (Apache Karaf 4.0.9 with Felix 5.6.2 I guess).

Comment: Does bundleB have its own copy of `com.example.MyBean`?

Comment: @NeilBartlett no, only bundleA contains MyBean class. BundleB has "Import-Package: com.example" and "Import-Service: com.example.service" which is a service to interact with managers contained in bundleA. When I show classes in bundleA and bundleB with "bundle:classes" Karaf command, I find MyBean in both bundles.

Comment: Looks like a packaging issue, looks like your build includes the class in question in both bundles.

Comment: @Hejk It seems you contradicted yourself. First you said "no only bundleA contains MyBean class" then you said "when I show classes... I find MyBean in both bundles". Also BTW don't use the `Import-Service` header, it is obsolete and does nothing.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck & Neil Bartlett, when I look at classes in my jars, I only find MyBean in bundleA. Not in bundleB. Maybe "bundle:classes" shows classes in the bundle's jar and classes imported by the bundle? Import-Service header is generated by maven-bundle-plugin because I have a <reference> element in my blueprint config file.

Comment: Hello, I'm still stuck... Does anyone can help me? :-(